# Double linked List prints only the last Value

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to learn how to program in C, and I'm having a problem with double linked list. If you test my code, you will see 2 errors.

1 - I'm having the Warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type". I saw several questions like this, my English is not the best, so I'm translating it =).

But, even with this error, the program compiles and executes. What brings me to the second problem:

2 - I insert names on the list, but when I print the list, only the last name inserted is printed, with the same number of names that I have included.

For example:

Inputs: Peter, Ryan, Paul:

Output: Paul
        Paul
        Paul

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Estrutura Lista
struct lista
{
   struct lista* alocar;
   struct lista* ant;
   struct lista* prox;
}; typedef struct lista Lista; 



Lista* inicia (void)
{
   return NULL;
}


Lista* lst_nomes (Lista* lst, char nome[50])
{
   Lista* novaLista = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));  
   novaLista->alocar = nome;                     
   novaLista->prox = lst;                             
   novaLista->ant = NULL;                             

   if(lst != NULL)
   {
       lst->ant = novaLista;
   }
   return novaLista;
}



void mostraLista (Lista* lst)
{

   Lista* x;

   for (x = lst; x != NULL; x = x->prox)
   {
       printf("Lista = %s\n", x->alocar);

   }
}


main()
{
   Lista* lst;
   char pegaTeclado[50];
   int imprimeLista;
   int resp;

   lst = inicia();

        do{
            printf("Entre com o nome a ser gravado\n");
            gets(pegaTeclado);
            lst = lst_nomes(lst, pegaTeclado);
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("\nDeseja inserir mais algum nome?\n 1 p/ Sim\n");
            scanf("%d", &resp);
            fflush(stdin);

           } while (resp ==1);



   printf("\nDeseja imprimir a lista de nomes?\n Sim = 1\n\nOu digite outra tecla para sair\n\n");
   scanf("%d", &imprimeLista);

   if(imprimeLista == 1)
   {
       mostraLista(lst);
   }

   getch();

}
```

Comment: C != C++. If you are learning C (and especially if you *don't* know C++), don't cross tag. Oh, and don't cast `malloc` in C.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to translate the structs/functions names:
lista = List
Inicia = Starts
lst_nomes = The list allocating the strings
mostraLista = Printing.

Comment: crashmstr, this is a homework, i'm having classes in Dev C/C++. The discipline is called Structure of Data, but my teacher seems to suck at it (and we students pay for it). So, everything i know i had to study on my own. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so there are a couple things wrong here.

the first thing is that you use the `getch()` function to block untill input, this can be done but it is part of the `ncurses` library and you need to initialize it properly.

the second thing is the usage of `gets()` this is unsafe and a different approach should be used. `getc()` until a new line is found or `scanf()` or `fgets()`.

the third thing is you have a mismatch between 2 pointer types:

novaLista->alocar = nome;

`nome` is a `char *` but `alocar` is `struct lista*`.

the next thing is that you cast the return value of `malloc()` this is not strictly wrong but can hide some errors so you shouldn`t do it.

then you shouldn't call `fflush()` on `stdin`.

the last thing is that you have to define `main()` as an int functions.

now to the root of your problem:

First you have a char array where you store your input. The reason it prints out the last inputted string everytime is because you overwrite the older ones.

you have defined a pointer in your linked list this means it points to a block a memory. in your case the memory that contains the string you capture from stdin. the same memory that gets overwritten when you get the next string. to solve this you have to copy the string from your `nome` into a char array that resides in your linked list.

the copying has to be done on an array. you have to allocate memory for the string and then copy it with `strcpy()`

```
Lista* lst_nomes (Lista* lst, char nome[50]) {
   Lista* novaLista = malloc(sizeof(Lista));  
   novaLista->alocar = malloc(strlen(nome) + 1);
   strcpy(novaLista->alocar, nome);   // copy the string
   novaLista->prox = lst;                             
   novaLista->ant = NULL;                             

   if(lst != NULL)
   {
       lst->ant = novaLista;
   }
   return novaLista;
}
```

If you fix all these things your code will work.

regarding indentation. this is really style but I prefer the kernel indentation style:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: Thx man! Your tips were very halpfull!, when i stop to cast the return value of malloc, the printed list prints only the last name, I saw some post about it, i will take a look.

And i was using fflush(stdin) to clear the buffer between the operations with string and int, i had in my head that this was needed to avoid conflicts. Thank you very much.

Comment: "copy the string from your nome into a char array that resides in your linked list" what do you mean? Create another pointer?

Comment: no copy it into an array. currently you just set pointers. if you copy you copy the contents of the array into another array. see `strcpy()`

Comment: Oh now i see, i will try that.

About casting malloc, i saw some people putting malloc in the "main method", what do you think about it?

Comment: you can do that but is no added value. if you have larger programs it will be nearly impossible to do that. It has no added benefit really

Answer (score 0):

In your function

```
 Lista* lst_nomes (Lista* lst, char        nome[50]) 
{ Lista* novaLista = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
 novaLista->alocar = nome;
  novaLista->prox = lst;
  novaLista->ant = NULL; 
 if(lst != NULL) { lst->ant = novaLista; }
  return novaLista; }
```

You are pointing a structure pointer to a character pointer. Try making the "alocar" a char pointer in your structure definition

Comment: Thx man, that solved the problema i was having with the Warnning about the pointer type, now i get it!

Comment: pls take a look at my comment there is more wrong here than that!

Comment: Yes, my code needs to be worked on :).
I will try to stop the overwrite problem.
Thx a Lot!